# Struggling with layer input/output shapes in tf.keras.models.Sequential

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Solved**

I wanted to try using `tf.keras.models.Sequential` and I noticed, that Conv layers take data in shape ( Samples, Dim, Dim, Channels), but output in ( Samples, Dim, Dim, Filters).

How can I run a second Conv layer over that output, preferably with 3D ( Dim, Dim, Filters) filters?

Conv3D asks for more dimensions (probably that extra Channel dimension). I realize I can Reshape, but it feels like I'm doing it wrong, considering it was less obtuse in original tensorflow syntax, where 2D layers can have 3D filters.

What am I doing wrong? Related code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer((28,28), 60000), # Mnist goes here
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((28,28,1)),         # black magic
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(12, (9,9)),          # outputs (60000, 20,20,12)
        # So a reshape goes here?
        # tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(40, (5,5,12)), # too many dimensions on filter
        # tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(40, (5,5,10))        # wants 5 dimensions
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(40, (5,5))           # should have done this, 
                                        # didn't realize it would iterate over all channels
])
```

Comment: why run a 3d convolution?

Comment: Because it doesn't let me have a 3-dimensional filter in Conv2D. I just realized I don't have to specify 3rd dimension for it to iterate over all channels. Fixed it, thank you.